# How to update a Streak box via API with google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Whenever a new row is inserted into my spreadsheet I would like to create a box streak.
The only solution I found was to create an empty box and then edit it with all the necessary fields.
The API call for modifying the box returns me:

```
Error   
Exception: Request failed for https://www.streak.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {
  "success": false,
  "error": "Missing parameters"
} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

This is my code:

```
function createBox() {

  var pipelineKey = "xxxxxx";
  var name = "sample box name";
  var url = 'https://www.streak.com/api/v1/pipelines/' + pipelineKey + '/boxes';

  var RequestArguments = {
    headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(STREAK_API_KEY)},
    method: "PUT",
    payload: {
      name: name
    }
  };

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,RequestArguments);
  var box = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
  return box.boxKey;
}

function editBox() {
var boxKey = createBox();
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.streak.com/api/v1/boxes/"+boxKey, {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic "+ AUTH_KEY
  },
  "body": "{\"notes\":\"note test\",\"stageKey\":\"5002\",\"name\":\"test from demo\"}"
});
Logger.log(response.getResponseCode())
}
```

If I put my parameters in the Streak demo the request returns '200 ok'
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv2Zy.png

STREAK API Doc: https://streak.readme.io/reference#edit-a-box

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of `createBox()` and `editBox()`?

Comment: I have a mobile app that inserts new rows into a google sheet. My goal is to create a new box in the Streak pipeline every time a row is added to the sheet. For now I was trying to create boxes with static data. But the editBox () returns me code 400. I used the API Streak: https://streak.readme.io/reference#edit-a-box
Thanks for your availability @Tanaike, I apologize for my English.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to use 2 methods of Streak API.

  1. [Create a box](https://streak.readme.io/reference#create-a-box)
  2. [Update a box](https://streak.readme.io/reference#edit-a-box)
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.
- Your `{"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(STREAK_API_KEY)}` can be used for using those methods of Streak API.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw the official document you provided, I confirmed the sample scripts of Javascript for [Create a box](https://streak.readme.io/reference#create-a-box) and [Update a box](https://streak.readme.io/reference#edit-a-box) as follows.

  ```
    // For Create a box
    fetch("https://www.streak.com/api/v2/pipelines/pipelineKey/boxes", {
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "body": "{\"name\":\"sampleName\"}"
    })

    // For Update a box
    fetch("https://www.streak.com/api/v1/boxes/boxKey", {
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "body": "{\"name\":\"sampleName\",\"notes\":\"sampleNotes\",\"stageKey\":\"sampleStageKey\"}"
    })
  ```
- From above sample scripts, in your script, I thought that `createBox()` and `editBox()` are required to be modified.

  - Please set the request body to the property of `payload` for UrlFetchApp.
  - It seems that "Create a box" is requested with POST method.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please confirm `STREAK_API_KEY` and the values for each request body, again.

```
function createBox() {
  var pipelineKey = "xxxxxx";
  var name = "sample box name";
  var url = 'https://www.streak.com/api/v1/pipelines/' + pipelineKey + '/boxes';
  var RequestArguments = {
    headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(STREAK_API_KEY)},
    method: "POST",
    payload: JSON.stringify({name: name}),
    contentType: "application/json"
  };
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, RequestArguments);
  var box = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());
  return box.boxKey;
}

function editBox() {
  var boxKey = createBox();
  var url = "https://www.streak.com/api/v1/boxes/" + boxKey;
  var RequestArguments = {
    headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(STREAK_API_KEY)},
    method: "POST",
    payload: JSON.stringify({notes: "note test", stageKey: "5002", name: "test from demo"}),
    contentType: "application/json"
  };
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,RequestArguments);
  console.log(result.getContentText())
}
```

#### References:

- [Create a box](https://streak.readme.io/reference#create-a-box)
- [Update a box](https://streak.readme.io/reference#edit-a-box)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)